# Does Orochi know Haise Sasaki?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Orochi reacted when he saw Haise Sasaki (*Tokyo Ghoul :Re episode 1*) and said

> Hmmm? There's something about him...

leading me to believe that he recognized Haise Sasaki from somewhere before. How did Orochi recognize Haise? Are they anyhow related from the past?

Answer (score 1):

You will get your answer in the anime *Tokyo ghoul :re* (**episode 2**)

---

Dialogs from Orochi

> No matter how far you go, you're always irredeemable, huh... **Kaneki**?

Haise replies

> **Nishio**.... Senpai.. ? (*Haise loses control here since he starts getting flashbacks from his lost memories*)

Answer (score 0):

Just... read the manga. Look, no matter how hard the anime adaptation tries it can never hope to possible achieve the success and rank that the manga has achieved.

Short answer: Yes, yes he does.

Long answer: Kaneki lost his memories after the events of the *Root: A* anime in which Arima kishou lobotomized him with his IXA, stabbing it through both of his eyes (this is not shown in the anime because Studio Pierrot are too PC sensitive) and Arima recruited him to become an investigator. Orochi is Nishio from Part 1.